# Problems with some extension tags in Wikimedia with FCKeditor

Tags: html-parsing, wysiwyg, wiki, mediawiki, fckeditor

FCKEditor doesn't recognise some new tags, so processes them resulting in garbage static html when users use this Rich Editor. The main example is categorytree. Many versions back FCK added support for new tags but this hasn't help me and I've tried a few versions and basically have given up. I have this problem on my XAMPP dev server and production linux box.

Below you can see my original explanations of my problem.

---

Turns out I'm only having problems with certain tags and protection of all tags was introduced a while ago.

My parser function tags are :

```
<categorytree>, <cso_source>, <gallery>, <nowiki>, <pre>, <skin>, <source> and <syntaxhighlight>
```

Tags that don't work:

```
<categorytree>, <syntaxhighlight>, <source>
```

The other tags work just fine, including the cso_source and skin extension tags

I have

- Updated FCKEditor, twice
- Ran maintenance\update.php
- tried updating CategoryTree to trunk (doesn't seem compatible)

Any other suggestions?

---

**Originally titled 'Protect extension tags in Wikimedia from FCKeditor'**

Does anyone know how to extend FCKeditor to ignore new tags, introduced by extensions, like the WYSIWYG ignores `<nowiki>`?

The likes of `<categorytree>...</categorytree>` and `<syntaxhighlight lang="php"> ... </syntaxhighlight>` are corrupted. They are converted to the resulting HTML by FCKeditor and reformatted rather than protecting the wikitext.

The best I could find is the following which GeSHI uses for Drupal.

```
FCKConfig.ProtectedSource.Add( /<vbnet>[\s\S]*?&lt;\/vbnet&gt;/g );
```

My attempts to use FCKConfig.ProtectedSource.Add failed and lead me to believe the problem is more fundamental for wikis.

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm running:

MediaWiki   1.16.2

 PHP    5.3.5 (apache2handler)

   MySQL    5.5.8

   MultipleUpload (Version 2.0)

   Special:UserScore CategoryTree

   SyntaxHighlight (Version 1.0.8.6)

   Widgets (Version 0.9.0-dev)

FCKeditor  (Version 1.0.1)

Comment: What versions are you using? Because I'm running the newest version of MediaWiki with FCKeditor without issue, and I have many extensions installed and working, including syntax high lighting and category tree.

Comment: Yes I see this was fixed ages ago [link](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/2432)... but not for me. MediaWiki 1.16.0 and FCKEditor 1.0.1 (r6448)

Comment: Sorry I have been meaning to get back to this. No. Still the same problem AND I have it on our 'production' server too. Fortunately it's only a company intranet service and most users have the Rich Editor (FCK) off by default.

Comment: @Stiefel let me know if you or anyone else has this problem. Maybe I'll find time to dig further

Comment: @KCD we only had the problem with our custom tag-extension. We wrote the extension from scratch based on the "balloon"-example - then it suddenly worked. We did not analyse further why, but its obviously possible to write an tag-extension that works correctly with mediawiki but does not work with FCKEditor.

Comment: @KCD I think the problem was to use the ParserAfterTidy-hook like it was explained here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Tag_extension. as I said: using the balloon-example that does not use this hook worked.

Comment: @Stiefel sorry for not getting back to this. Very helpful comment ([Tag_extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Tag_extension#How_can_I_pass_XML-style_parameters_in_my_extension_tag.3F)) thanks however I'm surprised the likes of categorytree wouldn't have covered this off, perhaps I should dig into the source one day.

Answer (score 0):

My current versions that are working... maybe something might help...

Product Version
MediaWiki   1.16.0
PHP 5.1.6 (apache2handler)
MySQL   5.0.77

Admin Links (Version 0.1.3) 
MassDelete (Version 1.0)
Semantic Drilldown (Version 0.7.2)
Semantic Forms (Version 1.9.1)
User Merge and Delete (Version 1.5) 
CategoryTree
Cite
External Data (Version 1.0) 
Header Tabs (Version 0.7)
Maps (Version 0.6.4)
ParserFunctions (Version 1.3.0) 
Semantic Compound Queries (Version 0.2.5)
Semantic Internal Objects (Version 0.6) 
Semantic MediaWiki (Version 1.5.1.1)
SemanticTasks (Version 1.3) 
SyntaxHighlight (Version 1.0.8.6)
TreeAndMenu (Version 1.0.9, 2009-02-15)
Add Article to Category
CategoryOnUpload (Version 1.0)
FCKeditor (Version fckeditor/mw-extension $Rev$ 2008)
LDAP Authentication Plugin (Version 1.2a (beta))
manageCategories
MWSearch
redirectOnLogin (Version 1.1)
Semantic Bundle (Version 0.4.2.20100719)
Semantic Maps (Version 0.6.4)
Semantic Result Formats (Version 1.5.0) 
TitleKey
Validator (Version 0.3.4)